# Could Nayirah be prosecuted by the USA government?

Tags: united-states, congress, law, war-crime

[Nayirah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nayirah_testimony) gave false testimony used by the President of the United States [George H. W. Bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_H._W._Bush)  to justify the first [Gulf War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_War).

She lied to the [Congressional Human Rights Caucus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Lantos_Human_Rights_Commission) at the age of 15 making what is now called [atrocity propaganda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrocity_propaganda#Gulf_war). The company who designed this "They took the babies out of the incubators" was [Hill & Knowlton](http://www.hkstrategies.com/global/) hired by Nayirah's father the ambassador of Kuwait in the USA.That line was developed by their psychologists to create the maximum emotional impact.

[Video in a nutshell here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vu8CCJTJCQk)

Would it be possible for the USA government to press charges against her or her father or even the Kuwait government for the lie and deception?

Comment: If your question is about the legal question "Is what she did illegal", you may find legal stackexchange a better fit.

Comment: Then , how about medias that collaborate with the government propaganda ?  This is usual political glasshouse fallacy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Her father was a diplomat and she may be able to claim immunity. Her father may have committed criminal conspiracy, but he is dead and can't be prosecuted for anything. Nayirah is living in Kuwait. It is generally impossible to try foreign citizens living abroad.

The testimony was not given under oath, so perjury cannot apply. There are laws of "filing false documentation". But these laws are really about tax evasion rather than this situation. She was a minor at the time which adds to the difficulty in prosecution and the case was a long time ago, so the statute of limitations may apply.

There is little public pressure for a trial, so little likelihood that the US government would put the diplomatic or military pressure required for Kuwait to surrender Naryirah.

In short, there are very many reasons why this won't happen.